# JTable Checkbox listener doesnt work properly

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I have a JTable which have Checkboxes.
This table implements the listener tableChanged, which fires an event selectionChanged with true or false if the Checkbox is selected or not.

In the selectionChanged, there is a counter to know how many checkboxes are checked. But this doesnt work properly. If i click anywhere on the checkbox it also increases the counter.

This is how it looks like:

```
@Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent P_evt)
    {
    .....
    listener.selectionChanged(F_newValue);

@Override
    public void selectionChanged(boolean P_selected)
    {
        if (P_selected)
        {
            nextButton.setEnabled(true);
            selectedBundles++;
            System.out.println("Selected Bundles: " + selectedBundles);
        }
        if(!P_selected)
        {
            nextButton.setEnabled(false);
            selectedBundles--;
            System.out.println("Selected Bundles: " + selectedBundles);
        }
        if (selectedBundles > 0)
        {
            nextButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            nextButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Comment: Every JTable of course has a TableModel, which contains the actual data. Why can't you handle this there?

Comment: what do you mean exactly ?, i have TableModel, but i dont want to change data of the table..

Comment: TableModel.setValueAt gets called when you check/uncheck a boolean value in a JTable. You could override this to count your number of checks or to keep a current value of checked fields

Comment: can you give a short example please ?

Answer (score 0):

@seriously

maybe this helps you more.

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private List<CheckboxValues> checkbox = new ArrayList<CheckboxValues>();


public void assignData( List<CheckboxValues> checkbox ) {       
    this.checkbox = checkbox;
    fireTableDataChanged();                                 
    }

//Fill Model with Data
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {

    switch( col ) {                                     // Es wird die Spalte ausgewählt
    case 0:
        return checkbox.row0;

    case 1:
        return checkbox.row1;

}


@Override
public void setValueAt( Object value, int row, int col ) {

    int columnFromCheckboxes;
    int numberOfselectedCheckboxes;

    if(col == columnFromCheckboxes ){

        if(value == true){
            columnFromCheckboxes++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: but is my solution false, it works , but sometimes it doesnt work properly and the counter increases if i click anywhere around the checkbox.. ?

Answer (score 0):

A change of focus does not necessarily mean that the user changed a value.

You should use a [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html) to watch for actual changes in the underlying data.

Here is a simple example of a [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html) that will count the number of checked boxes.

```
//Setup a listener for changes in the table
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        int selectedBundles= 0;
        //Count all checked boxes
        for(int i=0; i<table.getRowCount(); i++){
             if(table.getValueAt(i, COLUMN_NUMBER).equals(Boolean.TRUE)){
                 selectedBundles++;
             }
        }

        System.out.println("Selected Bundles: " + selectedBundles);
    }
});
```